# Simple Bash Parallel Tool (env_parallel dies on big env)

Tags: bash, multiprocessing

This is a simple tool to parallelize execution of multiple tasks in Bash, since `env_parallel` can't handle the environment size (or something of the sort - dies for mysterious reasons.) I'd love to hear your critique.

```
#
# Simple parallel executor. Takes a list of commands and executes each in its own child process. Assumes commands are distinctly named.
# Returns with 0 if all are successful. Otherwise, prints out their stdout/stderr outputs and returns with 1.

function simple_par () {

    local TMP_FILE="${WRITABLE_DIR}/simple_par_$(uuidgen)"
    touch $TMP_FILE

    for prog in "$@"
    do
        local PROG_TMP="${TMP_FILE}_${prog}_$(uuidgen)"
        (
            ( $prog 1>$PROG_TMP 2>&1 )
            echo "$?" >> $TMP_FILE
        ) &
    done

    while true
    do
        RESULT_COUNT=$(wc -l ${TMP_FILE} | awk '{ print $1 }')

        if [[ $RESULT_COUNT -eq $# ]]; then
            if [[ $(cat $TMP_FILE) == *"1"* ]]; then
                echo "Failed at least one command"
                for prog in "$@"
                do
                    echo "OUTPUT FOR: $prog"
                    cat ${TMP_FILE}_${prog}_*
                    rm ${TMP_FILE}_${prog}_*
                done

                rm $TMP_FILE
                return 1
            else
                return 0
            fi
        fi

        sleep 5
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things could be written better, let's go from top to bottom.

---

It's recommended to double-quote variables when used as paths,
to avoid globbing and word-splitting.
Even if you're certain that `$TMP_FILE` won't have any troublesome characters, it's a good practice to double-quote anyway:

```
touch "$TMP_FILE"
```

Similarly, you should double-quote `$prog` in `$prog 1>$PROG_TMP 2>&1`.

---

You can simplify `for arg in "$@"; do` loop as `for arg; do`.

---

In Bash, instead of `prog 1> somewhere 2>&1` you can write `prog &> somewhere`.

---

Instead of this:

> ```
> RESULT_COUNT=$(wc -l ${TMP_FILE} | awk '{ print $1 }')
> ```

You could write simpler without `awk` like this:

```
RESULT_COUNT=$(wc -l < "$TMP_FILE")
```

The trick is that when `wc` is used with stdin,
it won't print a file name, only the number.
Although `RESULT_COUNT` will have some whitespace padding,
if you use it in `[ ... ]` without double-quoting,
it will behave as expected.

Notice again that I double-quoted `$TMP_FILE`.

---

Don't use `-eq` in `[[ ... ]]`, use `==` or `=` instead.

---

This is pretty ugly:

> ```
> if [[ $(cat $TMP_FILE) == *"1"* ]]; then
> ```

A better way to achieve the same thing is using `grep`:

```
if grep -q 1 "$TMP_FILE"; then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @janos!
I'm a bit of a bash dilettante, it's good to have good advice.
Since then, I've rewritten the program to store the child processes' `pid`s into an array/string, and `wait` on each of them. It seems to be a better use of the tools at hand.

Comment: Cool, wanna post that up for review? ;-)